# How to run Cornelsen's "Tobi" software (for Windows) on linux, using Wine

Tags: linux, windows, wine, dll, runtime

There are a lot of resources on how to run Windows software with Wine, but this question is specifically about **how to run a software called "[Tobi Fibel](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/3060832889/ref=olp_product_details?ie=UTF8&me=)" from the German [Cornelsen Verlag](http://www.cornelsen.de/home/)** on (Ubuntu) linux, using Wine.

I got it partially working by just using the default settings from Wine, when installing the *Wine Windows Program Loader* using the *Ubuntu Software Center*.

The introducory screen of the software, where an avatar explains the software (with audio and animations) are just fine, also the mouse is working properly. However, **certain buttons do not work and it's not possible to go beyond this introduction.**

What I have tried

- Selecting between Windows XP and Windows 7 emulation mode
- Mapped Drive D:\ in Wine to point to the software
- Start from console instead from Gnome like `wine d:\Start.EXE`
- Start with the debug output like `WINEDEBUG=loaddll wine d:\Start.exe` The Debug output did not reveal anything useful to me.

**Update 1:**

When running the program in the debugger using `winedbg d:\Start.exe` and **press CTRL+C right after pressing one of the non-working buttons** I get

```
Ctrl-C: stopping debuggee
0xf772b430 __kernel_vsyscall+0x10 in [vdso].so: popl    %ebp
```

What can I do with this?

**Update 2:**

When starting the program using `WINEDEBUG=+relay wine d:\Start.exe` it just filled the terminal with a tremendous amount of logs and actually caused the program to show an error message right after startup. I did not manage to get to the point where I was stuck originally.

**How can I make the thing running all stuff, not just the introducory screen? I have no Idea what prevents the mentioned buttons from working.**

**Note:** I know that I could and have successfully run it on a Windows XP virtual machine, but I like to avoid using a copy of Windows altogether, for licensing reasons, and because the screen resolution (fullscreen required) is a bit flaky with the VMWare Player.

Comment: You will need to debug. See [Using the Wine Debugger](https://www.winehq.org/docs/winedev-guide/wine-debugger) about `WINEDEBUG=+all` for getting a more detailed debug report about what happens when clicking on these unresponsive buttons. You could post the relevant part of the result.

Comment: I have read thru the mentioned doc. But I have no prior debugging knowledge with linux and am a bit lost there. I have started the program using `WINEDEBUG=+relay wine d:\Start.exe` but this just filled the terminal with a tremendeous amount of logs and actually caused the program to show an error message at startup. I did not manage to get to the point where I was stuck originally.